# Python Excel floating point big difference

Tags: python, excel, floating-point

I used the following code to compute square root in Python:

```
from math import *

#find average of two numbers
def average(a, b):
    print "the average is",(a + b) / 2.0,"\n"
    return (a + b) / 2.0


    #guess not good enouhgh
    def improve(guess, x):
        print "improved guess is ",average(guess, x/guess),"\n"
        return average(guess, x/guess)

    #As long as the guess is not good enough, keep on improving the guess
    def good_enough(guess, x):
        d = abs(guess*guess - x)
        print d," is the currentguess\n"
        return (d < 0.001)

    #As long as the guess is not good enough, keep on improving the guess
    def square_root(guess, x):
        while(not good_enough(guess, x)):
            guess = improve(guess, x)
            print "current guess is ",guess,"\n"
        return guess

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        x = square_root(5, 33)
        print "final answer is",x
```

The result of the square root of 33 was :**5.74456521739**

I used the square root function in excel 2003:

```
=sqrt(33)
```

setting result at 15 decimal places and got the result:5.744562646538030

I then used:

```
math.sqrt(33)
```

from the standard  Python 2.7.2 math library

and got the result: **5.74456264654**

I then increased accuracy of my Program: return (d < 0.000001)

and got return **5.74456264654** the same as the my program

The question is why is Python rounding and Excel 2003 is rounding in different places. How can someone know which one is better to use in a critical situation? For example friends who are writing maths equations that need a high degree of accuracy in physics for a PHD thesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python and Excel both uses double precision floating point, which the precision depends on underlying C library, and it normally uses the hardware floating point unit.  Common FPU implements IEEE-754 double.

Having said that, I suspect you're using `print` statement which does the formatting.  See the difference below.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(33)
5.744562646538029
>>> print math.sqrt(33)
5.74456264654
```

Comment: never thought about that one , you were right, right under my nose.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `decimal` module to achieve this level of accuracy:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().precision = 15
>>> decimal.Decimal(33).sqrt()
Decimal('5.744562646538028659850611468')
```

In regards to floating point inaccuracies: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: That is fantastic would both progarms produce the same level of acuracy to the same level of precsion within the limits of double precision floating point?

Comment: @pythonMan are you talking about the answer by DhruvPathak?

Comment: is decimal a standard library or do I have to download it?

Comment: @pythonMan It's standard, try it out

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation.
If you want to use inbuild module, use `decimal` module.
Some external modules like :

mpmath : http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/

bigfloat : http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/

are also good.